# How to scrape 'src' or 'href' value when it uses Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Perhaps this is a simple solution, but I'm just really stuck on this one.

Say when you would pull the value of 'href' from a webpage using BeautifulSoup, for example:

`soup.find("a", {"id" : "home-page"})['href']`

How would you do this if the element looked like this:

```
<a id="main_lnkWool" class="WhiteLinkText Canela-Medium-Web" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$main$lnkWool','')">Wool</a>
```

When the value of the url is pulled from a javascript query?

I can see the jquery.js file the site is using, I'm just not sure how to pull the url using all the pieces together. All I'm trying to do is to use requests to scrape the url's of certain ranges of products.

Here is a link for reference: `https://www.kersaintcobb.co.uk/home`

The links I'm trying to extract are under the tab 'Our Products'.

I know there are only 6 pages in total, and yes I could just copy and paste them at this point lol! But it's a question I need answering anyway as I've encountered this same problem on other projects so would really help me out if I knew how to solve it.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best approach, but with JS sites what I have been able to do is use a webdriver, which is a web browser you can control from code (which you can make invisible btw, like hide it from sight). Wait till it loads then pass the source code to BS4. For more info: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Comment: My approach to this normally has had to resolve to using selenium alongside chromium webdriver to extract the information I needed. The only issue I have with this is that it is too slow for my needs. Sometimes I am scraping thousands, sometimes tens of thousands of products and I usually implement threading to make the process really fast. Is there no other way to pass the javascript query to the js file the site uses and call this function using the requests module?

Comment: No, not that I know of sadly, but someone may be able to drop some knowledge